# Importing feeds with PHP

Tags: xml, feed

I would like to create a customizable code to import some Feed RSS in Wordpress, using wp-cron.

I'm trying this but it does show nothing, can someone explain me why?

```
<? php

add_action('feed_event', 'feed_hourly');

function feed_activation() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'feed_event' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'feed_event');
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'feed_activation');

function feed_hourly() {
$time = get_option('lastfeed');
if(function_exists('fetch_feed')){
    $url = 'http://www.site/feed/';
    $feed  = fetch_feed($url);
}

if($feed) {

    foreach ($items as $item){
        $titlepost = $item->get_title();
        $description = $item->get_description();
        $itemdate = $item->get_date();

        if( $item->pubDate < $time) { } else {
            $my_post = array(
                'post_title' => $titlepost,
                'post_content' => $description,
                'post_date' => $itemdate,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_category' => array(get_cat_ID('FEED','Italia' ))
            );
            wp_insert_post( $my_post );
        }
      }
    }
    feed_option( 'lastfeed', $items[0]->pubDate );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `foreach ($items as $item){` to `foreach ($feed as $item){`

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Put in a debug statement within the function exists conditional to see if that function is available to you (it should since it's a native so function but it can't hurt) then var_dump $feed after that conditional to see if it's pulling anything in to look through.

Comment: You are going to have to call it directly so add action on init your feed_hourly function